# How to receive message in wechat itegrated in ios?

Tags: ios, wechat

I have integrate wechat sdk in iphone app. I can send a message with using SendMessageToWXReq class. But How i should receive the message within the my app.How GetMessageFromWXReq and ShowMessageFromWXReq works? Please provide me sample code.

Comment: Did you look at `onResp:`? At their sample code demo?http://dev.wechat.com/document/sdk-en/ios/index.html

Comment: yes...onResp method not called.

Answer (score 3):

`onResp` not called.

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url { 
        return [WXApi handleOpenURL:url delegate:self]; 
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
        return [WXApi handleOpenURL:url delegate:self]; 
}
```

Here,if you set delegate to `self` ,you will get `onResp` called in `AppDelegate.m`

If you set delegate to some other `viewController` instance, you will get `onResp` called in `viewController.m`

If this helps you, please let me know.